# How to import modules/plugins recursively?

Tags: javascript, webpack, tinymce

I'm trying to load all the "modules" contained in a particular directory. All of these can be individually loaded like this:

```
import 'dir1/plugins/one'
import 'dir1/plugins/two'
import 'dir1/plugins/three'
```

I've tried using something that sounded close to what I wanted to do:

```
require.context('dir1/plugins', true, /index\.js/)
```

This seems to load the files, as I can see their contents in the entry point, but I'm unable to use their functions later in my code.

I'm thinking I'm using `require.context` incorrectly, or it's doing something totally different as I'm understanding it. My goal is to not be forced to include every single plugin individually, as I want to load them all without exception.

Any hints?

Comment: Are these TinyMCE plugins you are attempting to load? I believe Tiny itself can only "find" plugins with the file name of plugin.js or plugin.min.js

Comment: They're TinyMCE plugins, yes. I know they have a plugin.js and its minified version, and they're referenced by the index.js itself on each directory with ```require('./plugin.js')```. I've tried to also load them with plugin.js, but even though it loads them (or so it appears) they're not available to be used by the TinyMCE initializer.